# How to speed up creation of all possible combinations in Python?

Tags: python, python-itertools

I am trying to generate all possible combinations from two lists as follows:

```
import itertools

products = ['productA', 'productB', 'productC','productD']
suppliers = ['supplier1', 'supplier2', 'supplier3', 'supplier4']

allPossibleSupplies = [zip(products, s) for s in itertools.product(suppliers, repeat=len(products))]

for i , val in enumerate(allPossibleSupplies):
    print (i, val)
```

The output in this example will be 255 unique combinations (product, supplier):

```
(0, [('productA', 'supplier1'), ('productB', 'supplier1'), ('productC', 'supplier1'), ('productD', 'supplier1')])
....
....
```

My question: is there a faster way to generate the same results in shorter time? this way is time consuming when number of either products or suppliers increases.

Comment: Not sure if you kept the print statement to judge how long it takes, but it'll run a lot faster if you remove it. For the record that line takes roughly 0.00015 seconds to run on my PC, though I quit an 8x8 attempt when it hit 6gb of ram :P

Comment: Do you really need the entire list in memory, or can you use `itertools.izip` to generate items on demand?

Comment: That is very likely. I tried izip but keeps giving me memory location when I want to use.
e.g <itertools.izip object at 0x103ca23b0>

Answer (score 0):

You must itertool.product the two lists of elements.
Then, I suggest to store the values in a mapping `supplier index --> tuple(product, supplier)` instead of a list

```
import itertools

products = ['productA', 'productB', 'productC','productD']
suppliers = ['supplier1', 'supplier2', 'supplier3', 'supplier4']

product_keys = {prod: idx for idx, prod in enumerate(products)}
allPossibleSupplies = {}

for elt in itertools.product(products, suppliers):  #<-- here, feed both lists to itertools.product
    try:
        allPossibleSupplies[product_keys[elt[0]]].append(elt)
    except KeyError:
        allPossibleSupplies[product_keys[elt[0]]] = [elt]

allPossibleSupplies
```

#### output:

```
{0: [('productA', 'supplier1'),
  ('productA', 'supplier2'),
  ('productA', 'supplier3'),
  ('productA', 'supplier4')],
 1: [('productB', 'supplier1'),
  ('productB', 'supplier2'),
  ('productB', 'supplier3'),
  ('productB', 'supplier4')],
 2: [('productC', 'supplier1'),
  ('productC', 'supplier2'),
  ('productC', 'supplier3'),
  ('productC', 'supplier4')],
 3: [('productD', 'supplier1'),
  ('productD', 'supplier2'),
  ('productD', 'supplier3'),
  ('productD', 'supplier4')]}
```